# Centering a Navbar UL (Unordered List) with Bootstrap 4 on OSX

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hmm, I can't seem to figure this one out on my own.  I'm working with the main Navbar and can't seem to center specific things on the page.  I already applied '.container' to 'nav .navbar' and set the 'max-width' to control where the "Brand" lines up.  But, I'm having problems with centering "Home | Link | Disabled | Dropdown" in the center of the page.

I've tried:

```
‘.text-center’ on the li tags, inline
and:
li {
  text-align: center;
}

‘justify-content-center’ on ul tag, inline
and
.ul {
      justify-content: center;
    }

Put the ul inside:
<div class="row">
  <div class="col text-center”>

  </div>
</div>
```

But, none of it works.  Here's the Nav markup and CSS file:
HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Here</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <!-- ul starts here -->

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- ul ends here -->
      </div>
    </div><!-- container placed within <nav> tag -->
  </nav>
```

Sass/CSS

```
body {
  padding-top: 56px;

  nav .container {
    max-width: 1374px;

    .navbar-brand {
      color: $blue-text !important;
    }

    .ul {
      justify-content: center;
    } 
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: Hi, did you need to align only the links or both the links and navbrand ?

Comment: Hi, Satheesh. I just need to center the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Satheesh, you put me on the right trail. I tried your solution verbatim in my Sass file but, for some reason, it didn't work.  Then I just added:

```
body {
  padding-top: 56px;

  nav .container {
    max-width: 1374px;

    .navbar-brand {
      color: $blue-text !important;
    }
    /* added from your solution */
    .navbar-nav {
      flex-grow: 1;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, if my answer works well, please Mark it as an correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To centering the navbar contents in the Bootstrap V4, use `flex-grow: 1;` it allows the element to expand 100%, and `justify-content: center;` property to align the item to center.

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
      flex-grow: 1;
      justify-content: center;
     }
  }
```

Here is the [codepen demo link.](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/MEjmLd)